# Gradle - projects with same folder but different paths

Tags: gradle

I know you can't include projects with the same name, that makes sense, but why does following not work:

```
include(":app:core")
include(":library1:core")
include(":library2:core")
```

I want the folding feature of the IDE that this approach brings as a side effect, but because all 3 projects end on "core" this fails when building the project.

Can this problem be solved OTHER than following:

```
include(":app-core")
project(":app-core").projectDir = file("app/core")
include(":library1-core")
project(":library1-core").projectDir = file("library1/core")
include(":library2-core")
project(":library2-core").projectDir = file("library2/core")
```

Using "-" or "." as separator does solve the compiling issue but then the IDE does not fold the projects anymore...

I really like to use the ":" style inside my open source libraries but when I want to include them in an app I get problems because more than one of my libraries has a core module...

**Question**

I wonder if there is some setting or other trick to get the folding inside the IDE and have the ability to have multiple core modules inside a project but in different paths and use those 2 features together.

Answer (score 1):

What is the build failure that you see?

I'm successfully using a multiproject build that has multiple subprojects with the same project name under different paths. The only change I had to make was this:

```kotlin
allprojects {
    extensions.findByType<BasePluginExtension>()?.apply {
        archivesName.set("myproject" + path.replace(":", "-"))
    }
}
```

I did it for `allprojects` in the root `build.gradle.kts`, but you could also do it individually for each affected project.

This ensures that each library gets a unique filename for the `.jar` containing its classes.

Without the change, `:library1:core` and `:library2:core` would both end up being built as `core.jar` and would conflict at runtime. After the change, I get `myproject-library1-core.jar` and `myproject-library2-core.jar`, and everything works fine.

Comment: Actually just knowing that it theoretically works helped - I've set up a global build directory `buildDir = "M:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"`  in my `init.gradle` file and I just realised the `name` is the wrong property for what I want. I changed it to `path` , clean the path and everything works.

Comment: @prom85 why do you go against the gradle convention? There are good reasons for things as they are, and going against it will usually bite you in unexpected ways.

Comment: I don't know which convention I break... I simply want a separate path for build files outside of my projects... I don't change anything else than that. By the way, years back the initial reason for me was that the build directory did contain too long paths for windows because my projects are already structured inside a hierarchy...